# docker mysql connection refused while connecting from PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, docker

Basically I want to run the LAMP stack in an Docker container. 
All services are so far running but as soon I try to connect to an mysql from within an PHP script I get following error:

```
Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  php:
    build: ./php/
    networks:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - './public/:/var/www/html'
  apache:
    build: ./apache/
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    volumes:
      - './public/:/var/www/html'
  mysql:
    image: 'mysql:5.6.40'
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      - backend
    environment:
        - MYSQL_DATABASES=test
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
        - MYSQL_HOST=127.0.0.1
        - MYSQL_PORT=3306
        - MYSQL_USER=user
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
        - MYSQL_MY_DATABASE=test
networks:
  frontend: null
  backend: null
```

Dockerfile for PHP:

```
FROM php:7.2.7-fpm-alpine3.7
RUN apk update; \
    apk upgrade;
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
```

I had tested it with the following approach:

```
docker exec -ti <mysql_docker> bash
```

and used the same crendatial for entering the mysql mode:

```
mysql -uroot -h127.0.0.1 -P3306 -p
```

and there is not problem with it.

So what may cause the above connection refused?

Comment: try host=docker-mysql instead of host=127.0.0.1

Comment: @RakeshJakhar, still the same. Maybe I should mention that I'm running on windows...

Comment: hi, from what I see you have the databse connection parameters hardcoded in your PHP container. Are you sure they are the same as the ones that you passed to the mysql container? It is a good practice to pass them as parameters to the PHP container to make sure they are the same. I suspect that could be an issue. Another thing to try is to connect to your mysql server with a client from your host machine. It could be that your mysql server doesn't accept connections other than from localhost....

Comment: Hi @Mihai, I had hardcoded them due to some tests, it is not intended to be deployed on live servers.The second point could be indeed an issue... I will get it a try. Thanks

Comment: @ChristianFelix also, how do you try to connect exactly to mysql? can you share the connection string/parameters? You should give your mysql container a name (with container_name: ) and then use that name in your php container. You can also remove the port mapping 3306 from mysql since you don't want to connect from localhost ;)

Comment: Have you ever fixed this? I'm having the same issue

Comment: @Skoempie, yes, I've switched to macOS, and Linux.